# What is the proper approach for multiple solutions and Nuget distribution

Tags: visual-studio, solution

I currently have a nice solution that works well with all projects included.  The problem occurs when I want to separate and distribute Nuget packages - one to group A, one to group B and so forth.  I've tried to separate all the individual projects into their own solutions and it works great! Great for handing off development tasks, for the separation of duties but hell in debugging, organizing and development time.  I'm wondering if there is a industry view that is being used to solve this byproduct of multiple solutions? (other than the Microsoft multiple solutions article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx)  A Solution of Solutions of sort.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, can you clarify?

Comment: I have different development groups working in the same solution.  Each doesn't want the other group in their stuff. IT vs Engineering.  I can keep with the single solution or convert the solution to individual solutions each producing a Nuget package that the other team can consume but neither approach seems fluid.  So... I'm looking for a best approach and this is where I need your opinion.  I was wondering if there was a methodology /workflow that I can use?  

Note: Some these Nuget packages would be distributed in the product and others run the business